# Trim command /imagemagick in command line to remove white space from iamges in /uploads folder

Tags: imagemagick

I can't work out the syntax.

Client has loaded 8000 images, all with huge whitespace around them.

how do i run a imagemagick trim command from the command line, that will trim all images in the /uploads folder and also from all files in subdirectories

Answer (score 0):

Is the whitespace always the same size? If yes determine it and adapt the crop options. Moreover you will probably need to filter on file name.

```
find . -name *.jpg -type f -print0 | xargs -0 -I{} convert {} -crop 40x30+10+10 {}
```

Comment: As emcconville suggested, use -trim instead of -crop 40x30+10+10

Answer (score 0):

Use [-trim](http://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#trim) argument with the ImageMagick's [mogrify](http://imagemagick.org/script/mogrify.php) utility.

```php
mogrify -trim /uploads/*
```

Repeat for sub-directories, or use [find](/questions/tagged/find) utility.

Comment: I'm trying this find ./ -name "*.jpg" -exec mogrify -trim /uploads/* but getting and error...

Comment: find ./ -name "*.jpg" -exec echo mogrify -trim /uploads/* \;  doesn't work either.

Comment: What's not working? Please updated your question with the error message. If [-trim](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php?#trim) has no effect, try adjusting the point threshold with [-fuzz](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php?#fuzz), [-blur](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php?#blur) or [-median](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#median) options.

Comment: OK... still going on this.

Have got this first command to run but now am trying a new command to shrink, center and add a white background

mogrify -resize 800x800 -background white -gravity center -extent 800x800 -format jpg -quality 75 -path thumbs *.jpg

getting this error mogrify: unrecognized option `-path'. 

even if i remove path, images are left aligned, and background is black, not white.